# Symmetric group $\left|\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}\big(\sigma(i)-\sigma(j)\big)\right|=\left|\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}\big(i-j\big)\right|$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> I would like a **hint and only a hint** to prove
>
> $\forall \sigma\in S_n$ , $S_n$ is a finite symmetric group of permutation
>
> $\displaystyle \left|\prod\limits_{1\le i<j\le n}\big(\sigma(i)-\sigma(j)\big)\right|=\left|\prod\limits_{1\le i<j\le n}\big(i-j\big)\right|$

thanks !!

Comment: HINT: It might be easier to prove the polynomial equality $\prod_{i<j} (x_{\sigma(i)}-x_{\sigma(j)}) = \prod_{i<j} (x_i-x_j)$, by showing each factor of the left is also a factor of the right (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: try by induction, starting from $n=2$

Comment: ok thanks for this help

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Consider the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another: prove their squares are equal, both being  $\prod_{i\neq j} (i-j)$.